# How to change the format of acronyms?

Tags: indentation, acronyms

I use the `acronym` package.
Please help me to change a gap between the acronym and full name of acronym and to put a dash between them like this:

> ```
> PG       - some text
>
> HRoT     - some text some text some text some text some       
>            text some   text some text some text some text some text
> ```

Also I would like to make the acronyms shown in Roman text-style (by default it's in Bold)

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{report} 
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{xunicode}
  \usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
  \usepackage[babel=false]{csquotes}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{french}
  \setotherlanguages{german,english,greek,polish,russian}
  \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
  \usepackage{acronym}

  \makeatletter
  \def\uplabel#1{{\normalfont{\textsf{#1}}\hfill}-}
  \renewenvironment{AC@deflist}[1]%
    {\ifAC@nolist%
     \else%
        \raggedright\begin{list}{}%
            {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\normalfont{\textsf{#1}}\hspace*{3em}}% change 2em to the desired value
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
            \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\uplabel}}%
      \fi}%
    {\ifAC@nolist%
     \else%
        \end{list}%
     \fi}%
  \makeatother

  \begin{document}
  \begin{acronym}
  \acro{Esj}{some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some textsome text some text some text}

  \acro{At}{some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some textsome textsome text some text some text}
  \end{acronym}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Extra dash
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file `acronym.sty` uses `\bflabel` to typeset the label in boldface and using small capitals; I defined a new macro `\uplabel` which uses `\normalfont` instead of boldfaced series and includes a hyphen to separate the acronym and its definition; this command will be used in the environment `AC@deflist` which formats the list of acronyms and will have to be redefined to increase the separation between the acronyms and their definitions. The `acronym` environment will also have to be redefined.

Add the following lines to the preamble (after the `acronym` package has been loaded) and change the used values according to your needs:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{xunicode}
  \usepackage[no-sscript]{xltxtra}
  \usepackage[babel=false]{csquotes}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{french}
  \setotherlanguages{german,english,greek,polish,russian}
  \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
  \usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand\acsfont{\normalfont}

\makeatletter
\def\uplabel#1{{\normalfont{\textsf{#1}}\hfill}-}
\renewenvironment{acronym}[1][1]{%
   \providecommand*{\acro}{\AC@acro}%
   \providecommand*{\acroplural}{\AC@acroplural}%
   \long\def\acroextra##1{##1}%
   \def\@tempa{1}\def\@tempb{#1}%
   \ifx\@tempa\@tempb%
      \global\expandafter\let\csname ac@des@mark\endcsname\AC@used%
      \ifAC@nolist%
      \else%
         \begin{list}{}%
                {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\normalfont{\textsf{#1}}\hspace*{3em}}% change according to your needs
                \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
                \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
                \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\uplabel}}
      \fi%
   \else%
      \begin{AC@deflist}{#1}%
   \fi%
  }%
  {%
   \ifx\AC@populated\AC@used\else%
      \ifAC@nolist%
      \else%
          \item[]\relax%
      \fi%
   \fi%
   \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@des@mark\endcsname\AC@used%
      \ifAC@nolist%
      \else%
        \end{list}%
      \fi%
   \else%
      \end{AC@deflist}%
   \fi}%
\renewenvironment{AC@deflist}[1]%
        {\ifAC@nolist%
         \else%
            \raggedright\begin{list}{}%
                {\settowidth{\labelwidth}{\normalfont{\textsf{#1}}\hspace*{3em}}% change according to your needs
                \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
                \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
                \renewcommand{\makelabel}{\uplabel}}%
          \fi}%
        {\ifAC@nolist%
         \else%
            \end{list}%
         \fi}%
 \makeatother

  \begin{document}
  \begin{acronym}
  \acro{Esj}{some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some textsome text some text some text}

  \acro{At}{some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some textsome textsome text some text some text}
  \end{acronym}
  \end{document}
```

EDIT: `acronym` environment redefined.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Thank you. :) But it doesn't work in my text. In code I've just put (your code in preamble) and in the document: \begin{acronym} \acro{DG}{some text} \end{acronym}. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: @filokalos: can you please add to your question a minimal working example including my code and illustrating the problem that you are experiencing?

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Shure. Sorry. One moment, please.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina I've changed.

Comment: @filokalos: I've added the necessary redefinitions to my answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina It work's wonderful, just like swiss watch. :) SUPER! THANK YOU very much! :)

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina The only thing is an extra dash at the end (the image number 2 above).

Comment: @filokalos: apparently the acronym `environment` always inserts an empty last item to the acronym list and that's causing the extra dash; I don't see a quick fix for that at the moment, but if I find out anything I'll let you know.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Ok. THANK YOU. It's already great. :)

Comment: I used your code to just undo the bolding of the acronyms. However, after doing so, it seems that the layout customization I introduced with `\setlist[description]{labelwidth=2cm, itemsep=0cm}` (through the `enumitem` package) is ignored. I can have the 2cm by modyfing the `3em` in your code, but I don't know how to set the `itemsep`. Is there any easy way to make this work? Or to still have the easy of customization via the `enumitem` package?

Comment: @Rabarberski please feel free to open a new fresh question.

Comment: @Gonzalo: done, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/176067/2090