# How to not have bold acronym, but still allow customization via enumitem package?

Tags: bold, acronyms, enumitem

I use the [`acronym`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) package to manage my acronyms. And I customize the horizontal and vertical indentation of the acronym list via the `setlist` command from the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. `\ac{MWE}` below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{acronym}    

\begin{document}    

\setlist[description]{labelwidth=3cm, itemsep=2cm}       % 2 cm is just for illustration purposes

Here comes the acronym list, unfortunately the acronyms are in bold. 

% Removing the bolding can be done by inserting the code from
% the "how-to-change-the-format-of-acronyms"  solution.
% but then the setlist customizations are ignored
%\renewcommand\acsfont{\normalfont}
%\makeatletter
% ... insert rest of code here
%\makeatother   

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{ATM}{Asynchronous Transfer Mode}
    \acro{MWE}{Minimum Working Example}
\end{acronym}    

\end{document}
```

The `acronym` packages bolds the acronym in the glossary list, which is not what I want. I tried to undo the bolding via the answer to the question [How to change the format of acronyms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15739/how-to-change-the-format-of-acronyms/15746?noredirect=1#comment407475_15746), and that works (after removing the dash). However, now my `setlist` customization is ignored.

Is there an easy way to undo the acronym bolding, but still keep the convenience of the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect there was some old versions of a package being used when you encoutered this problem.  The following [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) illustrates that using

```
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\normalfont#1}
```

does indeed make the acronym in a `\normalfont`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{acronym}    

\setlist[description]{labelwidth=3cm, itemsep=2cm, itemsep=5pt} % 2 cm is just for illustration purposes

\begin{document}    
Here comes the acronym list, and the acronyms are in bold: 

\begin{acronym}
    \acro{ATM}{Asynchronous Transfer Mode}
    \acro{MWE}{Minimum Working Example}
\end{acronym}    

% Removing the bolding can be done by
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\normalfont#1}
Here comes the acronym list again, and now the acronyms are \emph{not} in bold as we applied
\verb|\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\normalfont#1}|:
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{ATM}{Asynchronous Transfer Mode}
    \acro{MWE}{Minimum Working Example}
\end{acronym}    
\end{document}
```