# How to tweak acronym.sty to longtable width format and appearance?

Tags: formatting, longtable, acronyms, width

Is it possible to tweak the acronym.sty to accept the same width format as passed to the long table example below?

In other words going from

```
    %\begin{acronym}[USA] 
    %\acro{USA}{United States of America}
    %\end{acronym}
```

to

```
    %\begin{acronym}{@{}p{50pt} p{250pt}} % <-- direct example
    %\acro{USA}{United States of America}
    %\end{acronym}
```

The intention is to make the appearance of the acronym list identical to the longtable I am using for nomenclature (see example below). I would like to keep the functionality of the acronym package.

```
    \begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{50pt} p{250pt}}
    \textsc{Acronym} & \textsc{Description}\\
    \textsc{USA} & {United States of America}
    \end{longtable}
```

[How to change the format of acronyms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15739/how-to-change-the-format-of-acronyms) came somewhat close, but I am not near having the necessary know how for tweaking that .sty modification to something looking like the example given above. I am aware that the line spacing and column widths might make things rather complicated. Perhaps it would be simpler to redefine the acronym.sty to use longtable instead?

I am using the classicthesis.sty https://www.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis with no modifications; i.e. I am tweaking the ClassicThesis.tex.

Suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: I might suggest switching to the [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package which is very similar but more powerful and (most relevantly) has an option to print the list of acronyms in a `longtable` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spent a while looking at Gonzalo Medina's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15746/106162) to the question you link to I think it will at least be very difficult to adapt the `acronym` package to be used in a longtable.

Instead I'm going to provide one of those annoying answers which tells you how to do what you want in a different package.  In this case, the [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package which is not too dissimilar from `acronym` (same macros for using acronyms, slightly different way of defining them and generally more powerful).

The advantage [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) offers is that you can define styles for how the acronym list is printed by

```
\DeclareAcroListStyle{ThomasStyle}{table}{
    table = longtable,
    table-spec = | @{} p{50pt} | p{250pt} |
}
```

The first argument provides a name for the list, the second specifies the general type (i.e. `list` or `table`) then this is followed by a key-value list, the `table` key sets which table-like environment is used and `table-spec` sets the column types

Then we can set the acronym list to be printed with this style with `\acsetup{list-style=ThomasStyle}`

This will now print the entire list in a `longtable` environment with the column specifications given.

[image: Printed acronym list in longtable]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}

\usepackage{longtable}

\DeclareAcroListStyle{ThomasStyle}{table}{
    table = longtable,
    table-spec = | @{}p{50pt} | p{250pt} |
}

\acsetup{list-style=ThomasStyle}

\DeclareAcronym{pdf}{
    short = pdf,
    long = portable document format
}

\begin{document}
This is a \ac{pdf}

\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

As far as generally switching from `acronym` to `acro`, it should be sufficient to replace `\acro{shortname}{longname}` with `\DeclareAcronym{key}{short=shortname,long=longname}` for the simplest cases, the `\ac{key}` macro works in the same manner with both packages.