# Formating Acronym / List of Abbreviations

Tags: formatting, acronyms

I am currently writing my thesis and would like to re-format my List of abbreviations. I'd like to have the short notation bold, then a dash and a gap of a certain length between dash and full notation. I was able to make either the gap (see below) or the dash (by using the code from here[2]

I am using the following code for it the gap:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside, DIV=15,BCOR=12mm, headinclude=true,footinclude=false,headsepline,headings=openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage{acronym} % for abbreviations....
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Index of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index of Abbreviations and Symbols}
\setlist[description]{labelwidth=2.5cm}       
\begin{acronym}
\acro{DMPY}[2,6-DMPY]{2,6-dimethylpyrazine}
\acro{ASU}{Asymmetric unit}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

and dash [2]

[How to change the format of acronyms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15739/how-to-change-the-format-of-acronyms)

Is there a smart way to solve that problem? :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Shall "[2]" be the link to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15739/how-to-change-the-format-of-acronyms?

Comment: @Stefan, yes, exactly